# Date is not selected using JavascriptExecutor in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written code to select the date using javascriptexecutor but its not selecting the date. Here is my code :

```
 WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* 
 [@id=\"flightSearchContainer\"]/div[4]/button"));
element.click();
String datevalue="16-11-2019";
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Thread.sleep(3000);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+datevalue+"');", element);
```

Comment: You are trying to assign value to a button. Is it really what you need to do?

Comment: 16-11-2019 the date value i'am sending through javascriptexecutor to select the date value